# How to insert blob data into the embedded HSQLDB of Spring through the sql script?

Tags: spring, spring-data, hsqldb, spring-data-jpa, sql-scripts

This is my sql script creating the database:

```
create table product 
(id integer identity primary key,
name varchar(50) not null,
price decimal(10,2) not null,
image blob(1024),
category_id integer);
```

This is my sql script, which inserts data to the database:

```
INSERT INTO product VALUES (1, 'ProductName', 699.95, load_file('full_path'), 1);
```

According to HSQLDB, the full path is by default a relative path to database location. So what do i have to give as file path for my image files which are located under /resources/img/? (Spring creates the DB by using this URL:jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb)

Answer (score 1):

You can derive absolute path of class path resource as follows,

```
new ClassPathResource("img/abc.gif").getFile().getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: "from the sql script". Not from java.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem while configuring tests using **HSQLDB**. Seems like **HSQLDB** only supports `load_file('full_path')`, which takes in **absolute file-paths** only.

Alternatively to achieve the same result, use an *Embedded DB Configuration* in *H2 DB*.

The same query would be the below in a H2 Configuration.

```
INSERT INTO product VALUES (1, 'ProductName', 699.95, FILE_READ('classpath:filename.ext');
```

Answer (score -1):

See the description of param [`textdb.allow_full_path`](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_system_props).

It allows you to use different variants of file paths.